# Фатальная ошибка LNK2019, ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Проблема, реализовал класс для инициализации\сортировки, логику класса описал в заголовочном файле InteractiveSortUtil.h, а определил все в файле InteractiveSortUtil.cpp
При попытке сборки возникают ошибки линковщика (LNK2019,1120).
Гугление по ошибки как то не очень помогло, помогите пожалуйсат. Вроде как ошибка детская, и появилась сугубо из за моего незнания языка...

## InteractiveSort.h

```
#pragma once
// описываем необходимые файлы для включени, в данном случае заголовок для vector - типа крутой встроенный массив
#include <vector>
#include <random>
// Описываем структуру шаблонного класса, для ханения и сортировка вектора, в качестве 
// значений для инициализатора тип массива
template
class SortUtil {
    // Объявляем структуру данных для хранения массива
public: std::vector basevector;
public: size_t vectorSize;
         // структура для описания типов встроенных в класс сортировок
public: enum  SortType
{
    insertType
};
        // Стандартный конструктор
public: SortUtil(size_t _vectorsize = 5);
public: SortUtil();
public: ~SortUtil();
        // Функция сортировки, входящие параметры - тип сортировки
public:void Sort(SortType _sortType);
       // Рандомиизированная инициализация
public:void RandomizeInit(int lseed, int rseed);
       // Метод, для взаимозамены значений
public:void Swap(ATYPE &a, ATYPE &b);
};
```

## InteractiveSort.cpp

```
#include "InteractiveSortUtil.h"
// Определяем конструктор класса
template
SortUtil::SortUtil(size_t _vectorsize) {
    if (_vectorsize > 0) {
        vectorsize = _vectorSize;
        // инициализируем вектор размером ASIZE
        basevector = new std::vector(vectorSize);

    }
}
template
SortUtil::SortUtil() {
    if (_vectorsize > 0) {
        vectorsize = _vectorSize;
        // инициализируем вектор размером ASIZE
        basevector = new std::vector(vectorSize);

    }
}
template
SortUtil::~SortUtil() {
    basevector._Destroy();
}


// Определяем метод для сортировки 
template
void SortUtil::Sort(SortType _sortType) {
    switch (_sortType)
    {
        // Если это сортировка вставками, то структурируем память под ветку, и выполняем сортировку
    case (int)SortType::insertType: {
        for (int i = 1; i 0 && basevector[j - 1] > basevector[j]; --j) {

            }
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

template
void SortUtil::Swap(ATYPE &a, ATYPE &b) {
    ATYPE temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

template
void SortUtil::RandomizeInit(int lseed, int rseed) {
    for (int i = 0; i
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "InteractiveSortUtil.h"
#include 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    SortUtil b = SortUtil(10);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Во-первых** у вас везде бессмысленно написано `template` перед классом, каждым методом, и не объявлен тип вектора  - у вас НЕ задан тип шаблона, он должен присутствовать всегда и задаётся угловыми скобками

```
template <typename T>
class SortUtil {
public: std::vector<T> basevector;
// ...
SortUtil<int> b;
```

**Во вторых** у вас дважды определён конструктор по умолчанию, это может вызвать проблемы:

```
public: SortUtil(size_t _vectorsize = 5); // по факту этим вы определяете сразу два конструктора - по умолчанию SortUtil() и конструктор с параметром SortUtil(size_t)
public: SortUtil();
```

**В третьих** непосредственно ваша проблема - компиляция произошла успешно, но сборщик (линкёр) не смог найти реализацию конструктора SortUtil(size_t), это значит что ваш файл `InteractiveSort.cpp` не включён в компиляцию. добавьте его в проект (на сколько я понял у вас Visual Studio? тогда просто перетащите файл в проект)

Comment: Оба файла включены в проект, иначе бы интелисенс указал на ошибку. Но в любом случае, оба файла в проект включены. Насчет шаблонов, т.е необходимо явно описывать шаблон для конкретных типов? типа class<int> ... ?

Comment: @dr.Zilderman, вам нужен шаблон? вы вообще понимаете что такое шаблоны? если нет, то просто уберите. Если да, то внимательней их изучите, я удивлён что этот код вообще скомпилировался. Если ошибка сборки всё ещё воспроизводится, то подробный список её причин можно найти [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/5573683)

Comment: Нужна сортировка разных типов данных, соответственно, хотел через шаблон автоматически инициализировать вектор, код не скомпилился.

Comment: кстати да, не заметил что у вас вектор без типа, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Спасибо, убрал шаблоны, работает.

Comment: Чего то я про них (шаблоны) не понимаю :)

Comment: @dr.Zilderman, изменил первый пункт ответа